# Programatically access memory usage data in a running iOS app?

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments

How does Instruments access the memory allocation information in a running iOS app? I would like to write code that could monitor allocations created and destroyed by a class. Then, unit tests could be written to prevent memory leaks. Even if only a basic memory usage number is available, the unit test could read the number, create and destroy the target object, then read the number again and report problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_getInstanceSize()` can give you instance size of your objects. You can write macros around your code to get the total size required by them, but it's a good start.